# While trying to write if condition in list closures using groovy getting exception

Tags: groovy

While try to writy if condition in list closures i am getting exception like un expected token at if.

```
def supplerJson=new jsonSluper.parseText(json)
def details= supplerJson.get("student")
def jsonBuilder = new StreamingJsonBuilder(string)
jsonBuilder .root{
student {
 info details.get("address").collect { addres ->
     [
         "city" : addres.city ,
           if(addre.country.equals("USA"))
           {
             "country" : 123
           }
     ]
}
}
```

this is my code snippet while writing like this i am getting exception like unexpected token if is found at the line " * " column " * ". Can any one please help on this.
Thanking you.

Comment: Hiya! You can't put `if` statements into the middle of a map definition... I'll try and come up with a solution when I get to a computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to embed an `if` statement, use a [ternary statement](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_ternary_operator) instead, e.g.:

```
[
    "city": addres.city,
    "country": addres.country.equals("USA") ? 123 : null
]
```

A ternary statement is read as:

```
condition ? value if true : value if false
```

Groovy also has an [Elvis operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_elvis_operator), which is similar to a ternary statement and allows some other tricks, e.g.:

```
void doPrint(String message) {
    println(message ?: 'default')
}

doPrint('My message') // Prints "My Message"
doPrint('')           // Prints "default"
doPrint(null)         // Prints "default"
```

The Elvis operator's only difference with a ternary statement is that the `value if true` is automatically the `condition` statement.

This also demonstrates [Groovy truth](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_groovy_truth) in that `message` is converted to a boolean to evaluate the Elvis operator, and so empty and null values both evaluate to false, which prints the "else" value.

All of these are useful when you're trying to build inline maps.

#### References

- [Groovy Ternary Operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_ternary_operator) (docs.groovy-lang.org)
- [Groovy Elvis Operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_elvis_operator) (docs.groovy-lang.org)
- [Groovy Truth](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_groovy_truth) (groovy-lang.org)

Comment: Thank You Brain , its help full for me

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the question has loads of errors and omissions...

Assuming your Json was something like:

```
def json = '''[
  { 
      "student": {
          "address": {
              "city": "BoomTown",
              "country": "USA"
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "student": {
          "address": {
              "city": "Paris",
              "country": "France"
          }
      }
  }
]'''
```

And you spell `JsonSlurper()` right:

```
def supplerJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
```

Then you can get all the students:

```
def details = supplerJson.student
```

I took a guess that `string` was a `StringWriter`

```
def stringWriter = new StringWriter()
def jsonBuilder = new StreamingJsonBuilder(stringWriter)
```

Then you can build your json like so:

```
jsonBuilder .root {
    student {
        info details.address.collect { address ->
            def map = ["city": address.city]
            if (address.country == "USA") {
                map << ["country": 123]
            }
            map
        }
    }
}
```

And get the final json with:

```
stringWriter.toString()
```